# What are some forums/resources/methods that help facilitate getting a job in quantum computing?

Tags: programming

I've been applying to a lot of jobs involving quantum computing on LinkedIn now but the applications all seem to end up getting lost to the void and I haven't had even one reply from any of them. I was wondering if there is a better more effective way to get a job in this field?

Some background on myself: I have bachelor degrees in physics and astrophysics from UC Berkeley and took some of the first classes there offered in the field of quantum computing. I have mostly had professional experience with implementing post-quantum cryptography protocols and testing if existing ones have vulnerabilities that can be exploited. This sometimes involves implementing proof of concept demos which involve writing code for running quantum algorithms.

I'm really passionate about the subject and feel like its where I should be professionally speaking but I don't really see any obvious window to get into the industry.

Some helpful advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Also, apologies if this is the wrong board to ask this question. If such is the case let me know which one would be the best one.

Comment: I would consider doing a masters degree in the subject.

Comment: Hi @Crobs!  This question may get closed- it's not unreasonable to ask I don't think, but presently it's pretty opinion-based.  See, for example, this meta-question [here](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/should-we-entertain-career-advice-questions-and-have-a-career-advice-tag).  Perhaps editing the question to be less prone to opinions may be beneficial?  For example, editing your question to something like "are there forums for/resources for helping folks find jobs in quantum computing?" and then give a little of your background...

Comment: There are not too many companies that work on quantum computing. For starters, you could go through the job openings at places like IBM, Xanadu, Zapata and so on and see what qualifications they're looking for. Google and Microsoft are certainly the bigshots. Anyhow, I suspect a lot of these places require specialized degrees related to QCQI or at least a good track record in software engineering. A masters or a PhD would definitely help.

Comment: Given that the field is so nascent, I think that currently getting a PhD is the best path for a job in the field. A good reference for what industry employers are looking for in Quantum in the US can be found here https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.03601v1. Especially TABLE 1 might help answer your question